# Install plugin to the stand alone Qt Designer (not Qt creator) using Cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, plugins, cmake, qt-designer

I'm new to the Qt designer and I need to make a project which includes a speedometer, luckily I was able to find a plugin on the internet for a speedometer but the problem is I don't know how to install it to the Qt designer and to be added to my widget. I tried to search on the internet and all I found is how to install plugins in Qt creator. Please note that I use the combination of Qt designer, Cmake and visual studio 2010 (not Qt visual studio Addin) to build my project.

Here is the link for the plugin I want to install: https://github.com/efesler/Qt-Speedometer-Widget

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, do something like, download:

```
git clone https://github.com/efesler/Qt-Speedometer-Widget.git
```

then, you go into your downloaded folder and run `qmake Speedometer.pro`, then `make` and finally `sudo make install` and it is automatically added to Designer as a widget to be used in your form. However, in windows, I have no idea on how to make it appear as a widget in the designer. In any case, you can just add the code to your own project and compile it in your cmake and not with the provided `.pro` file. If you do so, you can use the `Promote widget...` option to add a generic widget to your form and make it be the speedometer that you downloaded.